# Why is hibernate-config/domain/Event.hbm.xml file is missing?

Tags: java, hibernate

I am new to hibernate, developing my first simple program, I got exception of missing Event.hbm.xml file.

I added it, copying code from the net, the I got Person.hbm.xml missing.

I added it then PhoneNumber.hbm.xml missing.

Am I missing some sort of library.

I am working in eclipse.

Comment: Check your hibernate configuration (if you are using xml based config using hibernate.cfg.xml file) for `<mapping resource>`. files mentioned in this tag is necessary to be present in your project. files which are not present you have remove the `<mapping resource>` entry for that.

Comment: Thank you Sir, that was the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there is hibernate.cfg.xml file used for hibernate configuration, you should check for `<mapping resource>`. File(s) (.hbm.xml) mentioned with `<mapping resource>` is must be present in that package if it's not found then it will throw the exception.

So either remove `<mapping resource>` entry for files that are not preset or add the files.